# Difference between String[] and String

Tags: java, program-entry-point, args

I was just wondering the difference between `String[]` and `String` in main method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
```

VS

```
 public static void main(String args) {
```

Comment: If you use later one than you will get exception: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main
Exception in thread "main" `

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`String[]` = array of strings

`String` = single string...

The `main` method of a program you'll run via the `java` command-line tool must have `String[]` as its only argument. The strings in the array are the command-line arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The main method in Java takes only an Array of Strings:

> The main method accepts a single argument: an array of elements of
>   type String.
>
> public static void main(String[] args)

Taken from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html).

I think that you are looking at an overloaded method of the main method, something which was created by someone else and is not the actual entry point of the application.

Comment: You mean an array of Strings, not a String of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

String[] is an [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) of String classes while String is an instance of String [class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/class.html).

The main method in Java **require** an array of string as parameter.

Comment: `String[] is an array of String classes` — simply not true. It's an array of *instances.*

Answer (score 1):

`String[]` is an array of strings while `String` is a single string , you can pass more than one argument to the main function so you have to use String[] and not String.

Answer (score 0):

Former can be used as the entry point for programs launched from operating system; the latter cannot (it can just be called from other methods).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute you class you need to respect the first way. The second way without using array don't allow you to execute your class.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute your program the `main` method is called and the command-line arguments are passed as individual strings inside the String array which is the argument of `main` (first case).

It's easier to manage than just passing the entire argument list as a single string (second case) and then having to parse it somehow (you can't build your program like this anyway).

Answer (score 0):

No such method if you are thinking to execute class using main

```
 public static void main(String args) {
```

`String[]` is used to signify that the user may opt to enter parameters to the java program at command line. We can use both String[] args or String args[]. The Java compiler would accept both forms.